# Shouldn't Java method parameters always be final

Tags: java

Say I have a method that writes a string to a file:

```
public void write(String content, File out) {
    // writes content to out
}
```

If I want to protect the parameters and ensure that they are not re-assigned a new value within this `write` method, I can use the `final` keyword to prevent this:

```
public void write(final String content, final File out) {
    // writes content to out
}
```

From what I know of best practice (and this handy [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245767/is-it-an-antipattern-modifying-an-incoming-parameter)
 here), this is a good thing - as it is not clear behaviour if a method  modifies what it has been given. However, I do still understand that sometimes we will need to do this and so the functionality should be built in to Java to allow this.

My question is, why do I have to explicitly state that a parameter is `final` and not the other way around? Why can't all method parameters (or even all parameters?) be implicitly `final` - and I have to use a new Java keyword (for instance`unstable`) to explicitly be able to modify a parameter.

```
public String write(unstable String content, File out) {
    // writes content to out
    ...
    // then for some mad reason, this happens
    content = "Done";
    return content;
}
```

This could be passed along into the Javadoc so that a caller could explicitly know that a variable they are providing is not safe and will be modified.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only answer we can provide to "Why did {somebody} do {something} instead of {my way}?" is "You have to ask {somebody}". In this case, {somebody} would be Oracle or its predecessors in Java.

Comment: @Rossair: Your wish is already granted! Java does not support call-by-reference, so a variable provided by the caller as parameter is never modified by a method.

Comment: @JacquesB your statements doesn't seem right to me, you can try to execute my code http://ideone.com/pU1SAb . Object(variable) provided by caller is modified here.

Comment: @Vipin: The variable and the object are different things. The variable `aDog` contains a reference but is passed by value. The called function `foo` cannot change the variable `aDog` to point to a different object. It can change the field `name` of the Dog instance, but that is a different issue.

Comment: @JacquesB This question is about modifying the local copy of the variable, which is certainly possible.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: No, the question states "This could be passed along into the Javadoc so that a caller could explicitly know that a variable they are providing is not safe and will be modified.". This suggest cal-by-reference semantics which is not something Java supports. Local copies of a parameter can obviously be modified, but that is invisible from the perspective of the caller.

Comment: A method call being final or not will make no difference to the calling context. I think what you are talking about is immutable (or immutable under certain conditions) this is an entirely separate concept to final. Make a variable final and note that you can still mutate the object it refers to, you just can't swap it for an entirely new object

Comment: Thanks to all above for clarifying - don't know why I thought Java had call-by-reference. Of course an object cannot be explicitly declared immutable in Java - so I guess this would be a limited feature anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be under the misconception that when `content` is modified inside `write`, that modification is visible to the caller.

It is not.

It's when you write to properties on it that those changes are visible to the caller, but `final` does not protect against this in any way.

Comment: Or, if you know C++, think of `final Foo` as something like `Foo *const`, rather than `const Foo&`. For *primitive types*, `final int` actually is `const int`, however.

Comment: That's exactly why I'm saying this is not how it should be - the caller has no idea what can happen to their variables!

Comment: But... the callee can't mutate their variables. Hell, the caller may not even *have* a variable, it may be an expression.